# as3 text formatting, Underline spacing?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, programming-languages, text

So if I want to imitate a link in as3, when I set

```
myFormat.underline = true;
```

the underline is directly underneath my text. Is there any way I can set the spacing of that underland? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a line instead of using the underline. Then space it how ever you want. Just make it the same color as the text.

Something like this in AS 3:

```
myItem.graphics.lineStyle(1);
myItem.graphics.moveTo(0,0); ///This is where we start drawing
myItem.graphics.lineTo(350, 600);
```

Comment: which class would i need to import?

Comment: Drawing the lines does work, however some of the links end up being 2 lines than 1. soo I'm not sure if it's gonna work.

Comment: You can draw one line or two. It will work. It is just vector drawing so any 2D effect is easy to achieve.